# when export to pdf it gives error missing parameter value

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

Please, say me why it gives these error but in upper postback code it shows parameter value while export goes in an exception:

```
var _exportOptions = _reportDocument.ExportOptions;

            _diskFileDestinationOptions.DiskFileName = obj.File_Storage_Path;
            _exportOptions.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile;
            _exportOptions.ExportFormatType = exportFormat;
            _exportOptions.ExportDestinationOptions = _diskFileDestinationOptions;
            _exportOptions.ExportFormatOptions = _reportFormatOptions;
           // _exportOptions.SetParameterValue("Parameter1", Convert.ToString(Session["myname"]));
            _reportDocument.Export();

            fileToOpen = obj.File_To_Open;
           // filePath = obj.File_Storage_Path;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error as " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            _reportDocument.Close();                
        }
        return fileToOpen;
```

Comment: it give me error while convert

Comment: Please post the error

Comment: ok...but now my error is clear but i get a string array and i want to print multi invoice into single pdf at now it takes only last number of array to pdf